# ImageMagick + MiniMagick error "error while loading shared libraries: libMagick.so.10"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, imagemagick, centos, passenger

I am running on Centos with Apache and Passenger and am getting the following error using ImageMagick and MiniMagick.

```
identify: error while loading shared libraries: libMagick.so.10: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have tried reinstalling ImageMagick, but it didn't help.

Also, when I run the "identify" command in the terminal on the server, all looks fine.

Any ideas?